# Autocomplete JS files - SharpDevelop

Tags: javascript, sharpdevelop

Is there a way to add auto complete for javascript libraries to SharpDevelop? Or is there already one and am I missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently. It is planned for a future version but has not been implemented yet.